# Environment Hub SSO Login via Apex/Jscript?

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning-web-components, environment-hub

We want to track when and why a user is logging into a customer's site via the environment hub.

Is there a way to detect the login event and pop up a form(Vforce/flow/LWC) to get input or login via SSO from one of these options after the form has been filled out?

I'm sure the answer is no but I had to ask.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of you doing this is to override the page layout of a Hub Member.

The problem you will have, which I am finding at the moment, is to work out how to enable the Org if it has not been enabled already.

You can also get around a page that has been overridden by adding nooverride=1 into the URL, so you might want to hide the standard login button and query the login URL instead to use that

This is the query you want:

```
SELECT  Id, IsSandbox, DisplayName, ServiceProviderId, ServiceProvider.SamlEntityUrl, Instance FROM EnvironmentHubMember
```

The ServiceProvider.SamlEntityUrl field will hold the login URL.